TabbedPage adding children content not shown
I wanted to dynamically show and hide a tab in a TabbedPage. When the app starts, all tabs are displayed correctly, but if I remove the tab and then add it again, the content of the tab is not displayed.
This is how it looks on start and after readding
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiTabbed.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="Yellow">

    <NavigationPage Title="Home">
        <x:Arguments>
            <ContentPage Title="Home" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine">
                <Button
                x:Name="ToogleBtn"
                Text="Toogle Tab" 
                TextColor="Black"
                Clicked="ToggleTab"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                BackgroundColor="White"/>
            </ContentPage>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Toggled Tab">
        <x:Arguments>
            <ContentPage Title="Toggled Tab">
                <StackLayout Padding="5, 25" BackgroundColor="Red">
                    <Label Text="Toggled Tab"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="18"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>

        Page _savedPage;

        private async void ToggleTab(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Children.Count == 1)
            {
                await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
                {
                    Children.Insert(1, _savedPage);
                });
            }
            else if (Children.Count == 2)
            {
                _savedPage = Children[1];
                await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
                {
                    Children.RemoveAt(1);
                });
            }
        }


How is this code behaving on windows machine?

On windows the page is displayed correctly even after readding. This behaviour seem to appear only on android and ios

This issue occurs sporadically. Sometimes it works fine but sometimes it does not. After debugging, I ran into a workaround which recreating the page again instead of saving a page.
In xaml, I just put a page inside a NavigationPage,
...
<NavigationPage Title="Toggled Tab">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:Page2/>
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>

In code behind, when adding the page, recreate the page again.
    private  void ToggleTab(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Children.Count == 1)
        {
            MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
            {
                tabPage.Children.Insert(1, new NavigationPage(new Page2()) { Title = "Toggled Tab" });
            });
        }

Then the issue disappears.
